# php javascript printing specific footer on every page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch a lot of rows from the database using php, and i have made a listing page as well, Now i want my client to print them as well. but on the listing page its paginated. I will override the query LIMIT though,

but i want specific HEADER and FOOTER to appear on every page. I have tried many ways but both don't appear. Header appear only on the front page and footer goes to the end.

I have used Bootstrap, PHP, and jQuery in the project. Any suggestions?

Also does Codeignitor has some support of printing pages? or bootstrap has media queries to handle this?

Comment: Print the header, then print certain numbers of rows (according to the page format), then footer... and loop... loop...

Comment: No other solution using css3? :(

Comment: your question is poorly worded and confusing.  and you list no code examples.  this makes your question 'poor quality'.  and that's why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) that is best for your situation !!!

Comment: Does this provide print functionality?

Comment: means can you be more eloborate?

Comment: I have mentioned in my question, i need to print the data ( PRINTER INVOLVED ) using browser.